# Perl Config::Simple

Tags: perl

I have a perl file that looks to see if an ini exists in a folder. If it does, it reads from it and if it doesnt, it creates one based on a template i made for it.

I am using Config::Simple for the ini portion.

My question here is, if i look for the file and it exists, how can i make sure the the ini that its reading has all the right setting names that should be there?

If the ini didnt exist, it would read from my template which will always be up to date but if I add a new setting to my code and their ini already exists, I need to be able to add just the new setting to theirs.

Any opinions?

Answer (score 3):

You can load the INI data into a hash and check the hash keys against your requirements:

```
my %config;
Config::Simple->import_from('settings.ini', \%config);

my @requirements = qw< foo bar baz quux >;

for ( @requirements ) {  # Verify
    warn( "Parameter '$_' is missing from INI" )
      unless exists $config{$_};
}
```

---

If you need to overwrite default settings, keeping the defaults in a hash will allow you to do this nifty one-liner:

```
my %settings = ( %defaults, %config ); # %settings contains defaults + overwrites
```

---

For clean separation of concerns, one might think of rolling it all into a subroutine:

```
use Config::Simple;

sub get_settings {

    my ( $ini_file ) = @_;

    state %defaults = ( foo => 1, bar => 2 );  # 'state' needs Perl 5.10+
    state @requirements = qw< foo bar baz quux >;

    my %config;
    Config::Simple->import_from( $ini_file, \%config);

    for ( @requirements ) {  # Verify presence of necessary parameters
        next if exists $config{$_};
        warn( "Parameter '$_' is missing from INI" );
        return %defaults;
    }

    my %settings = ( %defaults, %config );

    return %settings;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, here is my question / concern. My app will have a default ini (Blocks, settings and values). When the load the app, it will copy that ini template to their local drive and run it from there. If i make an update to the app and add, remove or rename an ini setting; I need to make that change on their ini. If the setting [options]Dog=woof doesnt exist on their ini, i need to add [options] and its settings / values to it. However, if that did exist but dog was now doggie, i need to update their setting but leave their own value there that they had defined. Is this possible?

Comment: Let me re-clarify - If the value doesn't exist at all (Added or changed) it will pull in the name/value from the template. If A block doesnt exist, it gets added. If the settings under a block dont exist, they get added. If the block does exist but there new settings, those get added to that block. Does that make sense?

Comment: @SBB : What you describe is sort of the inverse of my answer, because you want the default `Dog` to override the user's `Dog`. If the user has a `Cat` and the default does not have it then it will be left untouched. To make the defaults override the user settings, you want something like `my %settings = ( %config, %defaults );`

Comment: `[Settings]
setting1=1
setting2=2
[Options]
dog=woof
`

If this is the users ini on their computer but in my application, i define the template as :
`
[Settings]
setting1=1
setting2=2
setting3=3
[Options]
dog=woof
cat=meow
[Cars]
truck=big`

settings3 gets added to settings, cat gets added to options and a new section of cars is added with the setting of truck.

All im trying to accomplish is making sure that when i push out an update to my application, if the setting doesn't exist, pull it from the template.

Comment: Why don't you give my suggestion a try and see what happens?

Comment: I will, just a little confused about the format of the default options that's all. Will it know if what its adding is a setting or a bloc?